# How to iterate a variable in fabric ssh?

Tags: python, ssh, fabric

For example:

```
global count
count += 1
@task
def install(hosts, local_swift_config):
    env.use_ssh_config = True
    env.hosts = set_hosts(hosts)
    execute(place_count)

def place_count():
    sudo('echo {} > /home/user/some_count'.format(count))
    count += 1
```

It doesn't have to be a global, what is the preferred way to do this with fabric?

Answer (score 1):

```
count = 0
@task
def install(hosts, local_swift_config):
    env.use_ssh_config = True
    env.hosts = set_hosts(hosts)
    execute(place_count)

def place_count():
    sudo('echo {} > /home/user/some_count'.format(count))
    global count
    count += 1
```

I've had this work for simple functions in fabric. Your problem is with python globals, not fabric.

See this thread for more information on globals: [Stacokverflow Python Globals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function-other-than-the-one-that-created-them)

Comment: Thanks, I decided to not use `global`, and went with using the `env` variable instead. Thanks for the heads up. I hadn't ever used a global before, and was at the point where I would have used whatever worked at the cost of good practice.

Answer (score 0):

I decided not to use `global`:

```
def counter():
    env.count += 1
    if env.count == 2:
        env.count += 4

@task
def install(hosts):
    env.count = 0

    execute(counter)
    print(env.count)

    execute(counter)
    print(env.count)

    execute(counter)
    print(env.count)
```

Ouput:

```
1
6
7

Done.
```